# Set a default cursor for an application

Tags: c++, qt

In a Qt application, is there an equivalent to `QApplication::setFont` that sets the applications default cursor, to be overwritten by setting one on a specific widget?

`QApplication::setOverrideCursor` overrides all widget specific ones, I want local ones to take precidene over this one, but still use my cursor if I didn't specify one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QWidget either uses the cursor specified with QWidget::setCursor or falls-back it's parents' cursor setting. So, simply setting the cursor for your main windows should do the trick.

New top level windows and dialogs will need to have the cursor set when created since their is no parent from which to inherit.

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty close to what I need, however it doesn't seem to get inherited by other windows.
I guess there is just no equivelent to setFont though, so I'll have to handle a the others separately.